# postman does not store value

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, postman

So I am trying to enter a post using postman into a mongo db server but my post just returns empty. When I look into my server nothing has been entered and there is no error

Route file

```
router.post('/', async (req,res) => {
const post = new customer({
    fullName: req.body.fullName,
    id: req.body.id
});
try{
    const savedCust = await customer.save();
    res.json(savedCust);
} catch (err) {
    res.json({message: err});
}
});

module.exports = router;
```

This is what I submit on postman:

```
{
    "fullName" : "Tim Scott",
    "id": 87438
}
```

And this is the response that I get back:

```
{
    "message": {}
}
```

Comment: Inside `catch (err) {...}` add `console.log("ERROR:", err);` and check your logs again for something starting with `ERROR:`. The error message likely wasn't JSON encodable and resulted in an empty string. Also, I would recommend sending all the details of your error message to the client. Just log it, give the client a status code and tell them to try again later.

Comment: OH MY GOD thank you so much idk why I didn't even think of that. ok it says that customer.save() is not defined so I just have to figure that out now and how to fix it

Comment: Typo in my last comment. I **wouldn't** recommend sending all the details of your error message to your client.

Comment: I found your error. Inside your `try` statement you should be doing `post.save()` instead of `customer.save()`, hope that helps? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error said that `customer.save()` isn't a function. This happened in your `try {...}` block inside your route file. The reason for that is that it's *not* a function. You should be doing `post.save()`:

```js
// route file
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const customer = require('../models/customer');
router.post('/', async (req,res) => {
  const post = new customer({
    fullName: req.body.fullName,
    id: req.body.id
  });
  try {
    const savedCust = await post.save(); // right here
    res.json(savedCust);
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({message: err});
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: @Rhythm glad it worked for you. Happy coding! :)

Comment: @Rhythm would you mind selecting it as the correct anwer?